# Using Postman and AWS Lambdas to upload and download to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have 2 lambda functions, to upload and downlaod a file from an S3 bucket.  Im using Postman and configuring the POST and GET requests to have either a filename sent via json (GET Json payload: `{"thefile" : "test_upload.txt"}` ) and have set a form-data key of "thefile" and the value with the test file selected from my working directory on the computer.

The issue comes when sending the API requests via postman.  Its giving me 'Internal Server Error'

The code for my lambdas is below:

**UPLOAD **

```
import json
import boto3
import os

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    data = json.loads(event["body"])
    file = data["thefile"]
    print(file)
    try:
        s3.upload_file(file, os.environ['BUCKET_NAME'], file)
        url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
            ClientMethod='get_object',
            Params={
                'Bucket': os.environ['BUCKET_NAME'],
                'Key': file
            },
            ExpiresIn=24 * 3600
        )

        print("Upload Successful", url)
        return {
            "headers": { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            "statusCode": 200,
            "isBase64Encoded": False,
            "body":  str(url)
        }
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("The file was not found")
        return {
            "headers": { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            "statusCode": 404,
            "isBase64Encoded": False,
            "body":  "File not found"
        }
```

**DOWNLOAD **

```
import json
import boto3
import botocore
import base64
from botocore.vendored import requests

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    data = json.loads(event["body"])
    file = data["thefile"]
    try:
        response = s3.get_object(Bucket=BUCKET_NAME, Key=file,)
        download_file = response["Body"].read() 
        filereturn = base64.b64encode(download_file).decode("utf-8")
        return { 
        "headers": { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps(filereturn),
        "isBase64Encoded": True,
        "File Downloaded": "File Downloaded successfully"
        }
    except Exception as e:
        return { 
        "headers": { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        "statusCode": 404,
        "body": "Error: File not found!"
        }
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  The Lambdas have full access to S3 in their policy, I've even switched off authorisation and made the bucket public in case it was a permissions error but still nothing.  It must be something stupid im either forgetting or have mis-coded but I cant for the life of me figure it out!

Comment: What do the CloudWatch Logs for this Lambda function invocation tell you? PS it's not clear to me how your upload code will ever throw FileNotFoundError or why you would return 404 for a failed upload.

Comment: The logs dont have anything after 18th August, for the upload or download lambdas.  Its switched on, but nothing is showing?

Comment: Managed to get a log via the API Gateway test functionality:

Wed Aug 31 10:10:59 UTC 2022 : Lambda execution failed with status 200 due to customer function error: 2022-08-31T10:10:59.712Z 1a2f5810-fd20-4e5c-8ae3-f9f8e07a3a99 Task timed out after 3.01 seconds. Lambda request id: 1a2f5810-fd20-4e5c-8ae3-f9f8e07a3a99 Wed Aug 31 10:10:59 UTC 2022 : Method completed with status: 502`

Looks like its raising an issue with the function itself?

Comment: Assuming you're confident that your code is good, it sounds like you attached the Lambda function to VPC and it doesn't have a network route so it times out when trying to reach S3. Most Lambda functions don't need to be in VPC so, if that's also the case here, then re-configure it.